# How to Share data between two python applications using Multiprocessing.Queue()?

Tags: python, flask, rabbitmq

I want to share data between Flask Server application and rabbitmq consumer. currently i was using multiprocessing for parallel running of two applications. I want to share the consumed data from rabbitmq consumer to Flask application. can anyone help to achieve this ?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have created two processess in my main method. I also created two multiprocessing queues in my main method and tried to pass the queue to the processess. since my processes are two applications i was unable to collect those queues and use it.